# Select Text from Paragraph and replace that text with Input Value-Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

My Jquery for taking the paragrapgh selected text in the textarea and replace its text with the selected text:

```
function getSelectedText(){
 var sel = window.getSelection(), range;
 if(sel.getRangeAt)
        {
          range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
          if(range != "")
          {
            return range;
          }
        }
      }

      // Show Suggestion Box
      $(document).ready(function(){

       $("#selector").on('mouseup',function(){
            // $('#editor').animate({width: 'toggle'});
            $("#editor").show(1000);

            $("#btn_close_editor").show(1000);

            $('#comment').val(''+getSelectedText());
       }); 
      });

      $(document).ready(function(){
       $( "#comment" ).focus(function() {
              });
      });

      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#btn_update_editor').click(function(){

              var string = getSelectedText();

              var rep = $("#comment").val()

              $("#selector p").each(function () {
                $(this).text($(this).text().replace(string, ''+rep))

              });

          });
      });
```

```
<div id="selector">
  <p>
   //My Paragrapgh
  </p>
  <div id="editor" >

            <textarea id="comment" class="form-control" rows = 5 placeholder="Description"></textarea>
            <hr>
            <button id="btn_update_editor" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button> 
        </div>
 </div>
```

Tell me Please How I can replace the Selected text from getSelectedText() function with the input Text in the , I have tried alot but could just replace it..Any body Can help me out here??

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what `getSelectedText()` returns but this should pretty much do it.

`$('#selector p:first').html('whatever you want in here');`

Comment: the getSelectedText() return the range You select in the paragraph.

Comment: In which case plug that in where I wrote `whatever you want in here`  To be honest, your code should be pretty much doing what you want in anycase?  If you're still struggling I can highly recommend you setup a bare-bones JSfiddle.net with all the parts needed so others can help easier.